# How to use JSON.Net in a refactoring safe way for persistent data

Tags: c#, json, refactoring, migration, json.net

I'm using JSON.Net to save collections of objects inheriting from an interface. I've found I can set [TypeNameHandling](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) as in

```
JsonSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

and I can get the fully qualified type name of the objects injected into the emitted json which can be used on serialization to construct the correct object.

```
"$type": "Newtonsoft.Json.Samples.Hotel, Newtonsoft.Json.Tests"
```

However I'm pretty trigger happy with my resharper refactoring and this kind of mapping will break quickly between versions of the code.

What I'd like to to is instead of storing the fully qualified typename I would assign each class a Guid as a type id which will never change under refactoring and use that to map back to the deserialization code.

Is this something someone has tried before and if so how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

We now have an open source project to help with migrations.

https://github.com/Weingartner/Migrations.Json.Net

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here is the JsonConverter I wrote to solve **my** problem. What I did was use the **Guid** attribute ( which is normally used for com interop ) to tag my serialization. I then provided a factory based on the guid. The factory was based on the ninject DI framework.

The critical line of code is in the ReadJson method

```
var document = _Kernel.Get<IWeinCadDocument>(typeId.ToString());
```

here I create an instance of my document of the correct type based on the Guid string. The types are pre-registered using the following function.

```
public void BindDocumentTypes(params Type[] types)
{
    Debug.Assert
        (types.All(p => typeof (IWeinCadDocument).IsAssignableFrom(p)));
     foreach (var documentType in types)
    {
        Kernel.Bind<IWeinCadDocument>()
              .To(documentType)
              .Named(documentType.GUID.ToString());
    }
}
```

which can be used in the following way to register a set of types with their Guid.

```
BindDocumentTypes(
    typeof (ADocument), typeof (BDocument), typeof (CDocument)
);
```

To make sure the Guid does not change between versions of the software or even compiles we enforce the Guid like so with an attribute.

```
[Guid("4882176A-751A-4153-928A-915BEA87FAB3")]
public class ADocument : WeinCadDocumentBase<ADocument>
{
    public ADocument( IWeinCadDocumentStorage storage )
        : base(storage)
    {
    }

    public override object PersistentData
    {
        get
        {
            return new DocumentData(10, 20);
        }
    }


}
```

the full JSonConverter is below.

```
public class WeinCadDocumentConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly IKernel _Kernel;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var document = value as IWeinCadDocument;
        Debug.Assert(document != null, "document != null");

        AssertThatWeHaveACustomGuidSet(value);

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("InstanceId");
        writer.WriteValue(document.InstanceId);
        writer.WritePropertyName("TypeId");
        writer.WriteValue(document.GetType().GUID);
        writer.WritePropertyName("Name");
        writer.WriteValue(document.Name);
        writer.WritePropertyName("Data");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, document.PersistentData);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The object need a custom GuidAttribute to be set on the class otherwise the
    /// GUID may change between versions of the code or even runs of the applications.
    /// This Guid is used for identifying types from the document store and calling
    /// the correct factory. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    private static void AssertThatWeHaveACustomGuidSet(object value)
    {
        var attr = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(value.GetType())
                         .Where(a => a is GuidAttribute)
                         .ToList();

        if (attr.Count == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException
                (String.Format
                     (@"Type '{0}' does not have a custom GuidAttribute set. Refusing to serialize.",
                      value.GetType().Name),
                 "value");
    }

    public override object ReadJson
        (JsonReader reader,
         Type objectType,
         object existingValue,
         JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject json = JObject.Load(reader);
        var props = json.Properties().ToList();
        var instanceId = (Guid) props[0].Value;
        var typeId = (Guid) props[1].Value;
        var name = (string) props[2].Value;
        var data = props[3].Value;

        var document = _Kernel.Get<IWeinCadDocument>(typeId.ToString());

        document.PersistentData = data;
        document.InstanceId = instanceId;
        document.Name = name;

        return document;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof (IWeinCadDocument).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public WeinCadDocumentConverter(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _Kernel = kernel;
    }
}
```